# set multiline in regex_search

Tags: c++, regex

I want search Pattern ("*.txt") and I must be use multiline for best result, and my pattern is

```
.*[ \t]*\.[ \t]*txt[ \t]*$
```

if add to end above pattern $ I haven't result and if I removed $ from end of pattern I have :

```
test.txt.log  // it not right result
Test.txt
```

and so on.

My code is :

```
std::regex_search(filename, searchPattern, std::regex_constants::match_continuous)
```

how can i fix this problem?

Comment: You may use `(?=\r?\n|$)`, for example, instead of `$`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i do, i have not result, it's incorrect

Comment: The pattern change I suggested *is* correct provided you are using the default regex flavor. Please share the whole relevant snippet to repro the issue.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in site https://www.regextester.com/97722 we can set pattern and in flags section we can set flag to multiline,  this pattern in multiline flag is good and right, and my question is : how can i set multiline in c++, i search in internet but anybody tell this cann't do...

Comment: It is easy to answer: there is no such an option in std::regex. Use the solution I provided in the top comment. Else, use Boost.

Comment: can you explain what you exactly want to achieve ? I dont see any multiline usage here ... you can always read line by line (for ex. using sstream) and regex against single line.

Comment: @StPiere please study http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0014r1.html